# Appropriate design for hierarchy object initialization

Tags: design-patterns

I am not sure what is the appropriate design for my program.
I like to develop a code that contain 3 types (levels).

1. Manager
2. Officer
3. Employee

while the Employee has some fields, the Officer has the same fields with some extension and the Manager have all (they inherits one from each other).

My question is what appropriate design should I use to build those objects?
I thought about:
1. "Builder" design, which can create part of the object and you can extend it,       if you need to use higher level.
2. Some articles point that I should use "Composite" design.

Any advise will be blessed , Im open for suggestion and for new design.
IF you can please add example.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. What is the problem with `new Manager()` to construct a Manager, and `new Officer()` to construct an Officer? Could you post code, and explain the problem you're facing?

Comment: The question is about a good design to use when I need to create an instance of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Composite is appropriate here. What's wrong with a good old Factory/FactoryMethod?

Comment: I'm using the Factory design, but I wonder if there is a better way to write this code. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with a factory?